# Jackson InputCoercionException: replace numbers out of range

Tags: java, jackson

I am getting an `InputCoercionException` from Jackson when reading JSONs that contain too large numbers.

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.exc.InputCoercionException: Numeric value (2328461700) out of range of int (-2147483648 - 2147483647)
```

Is it possible to configure Jackson to replace values that are out of range - for example, with a `-1`? If not, is there any solution to parse the value without changing the type to double?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you cannot replace values out of range using [Jackson's Deserialization Features](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Deserialization-Features).

But you can easily create a custom deserializer and handle the values as you need.

There are tutorials and good examples on [Baeldnung's](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization) or [Jenkov's](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-objectmapper.html#custom-deserializer) blogs.